# Oracle SOA query with wildcards needed

Tags: sql, oracle, soa, wildcard

So I'm building a query that accepts a single parameter. That parameter basically is a string that might appear in a column.

```
SELECT ID, SEARCH_STRING 
FROM SEARCH_RESULTS 
WHERE UPPER(SEARCH_STRING) LIKE UPPER('%test%');
```

The query above work exactly as expected. It looks in the table and returns any records where test appears in the search string column.

Now to my actual problem. In SOA I created the parameter that will be the search value. VALUE. Basically the query ends up

```
SELECT ID, SEARCH_STRING 
FROM SEARCH_RESULTS 
WHERE UPPER(SEARCH_STRING) LIKE UPPER(#VALUE)
```

But I lose the ability to keep the wildcards. I've tried (%#VALUE%), ('%'#VALUE'%'), and ('%#VALUE%') all don't work.

Thank everyone

Comment: I'm not familiar with SOA but this might work: `...WHERE UPPER(SEARCH_STRING) LIKE '%'||UPPER(#VALUE)||'%';`

Comment: @JeffreyKemp: Post your comment as the answer ^^.

Comment: Thank you Jeffrey concatenation did the trick. When dealing with parameters you can't append the wildcards directly because the parameter automatically adds the formatting for the value directly so adding the % directly next to the parameter did not work. I though about doing the same thing late last night and tested it first thing this morning.

Answer (score 2):

ok.... :)

```
...WHERE UPPER(SEARCH_STRING) LIKE '%'||UPPER(#VALUE)||'%';
```